# How to get the CPU usage % of Amazon Web Server via JMeter?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jmeter, performance-testing, cpu-usage, perfmon

I am using an application for which I do have server of Amazon(AWS).
I need to make use of Jmeter Perfmon plugin, but unfortunately I do not have access to AWS(They do not allow basically).

So what should I need to do to have CPU usage% of AWS?

Answer (score 0):

AWS provides CPU metrics through a web UI as well as API calls. For more information [see here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/US_SingleMetricPerInstance.html).

Please note that only 5min interval and above for no charge. For most performance tests, you'll want more granular data, 1 min is available, but isn't free.